# How to write backpropagation process in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I built a multi-output model. All articles instruct to add up all losses and then look backward, but this means that the loss of output_a will affect the weight of output_b. This doesn't seem right in my imagination. Is there any way to prevent them from causing each other?

```
class NN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NN, self).__init__()
        self.lin1 = torch.nn.Linear(784, 128)
        self.out_a = torch.nn.Linear(128, 10)
        self.out_b = torch.nn.Linear(128, 6)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.lin1(x)
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(x)
        out_a = self.out_a(x)
        out_b = self.out_b(x)
        return out_a, out_b

model = NN()

optimizer.zero_grad()
y_pred_a, y_pred_b = model(x_train)
loss_a = criterion_a(y_pred_a, y_train_a)
loss_b = criterion_b(y_pred_b, y_train_b)
loss = loss_a + loss_b
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent them from causing each other"? You don't *have* to add the losses from using `out_a` and `out_b` if you logically don't need to. You would likely do that if their results are dependent on each other, or other reasons, but you don't have to just because you always read other people do that for their use cases.

Comment: I hope that the loss of out_a will only affect the weight of lin1 and out_a, but not the weight of out_b. In the same way, I hope that the loss of out_b will only affect the weight of lin1 and out_b, but not the weight of out_a.

Comment: So you want two separate models?